# Saving memory in VBA, after ScreenUpdating is turned off, periodic saving and repeating and rewriting existing data few times

Tags: excel, vba, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to save memory in excel, as I am trying to run a large Monte Carlo simulation, with 30k entries and 10k simulations.

The following are already implemented steps to save memory:

```
1. Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

2. If (sims * inputlength) > 24000000 Then
      originalsims = sims
      sims = Int((24000000 / inputlength))
      repeats = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((originalsims / sims), 0)
End If
```

I realised that if the number of inputs * simulations exceed the number of 24mio, it gives a memory issue, so I break down total number of simulations and repeat the whole process x times, to reach the initially desired number of simulations.

```
3. ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

I've read somewhere that if I save the file once in a while (I do it every 1000 simulations) this will also preserve some memory.

Questions:

1. Not relevant -> deleted.
2. How to further improve memory issues and not having to let the macro run for approx. 30 minutes each time?

Comment: 1.) There's nothing with a subscript in the code provided, so that won't be answerable without seeing the code around where the error is thrown. 2.) The memory "issue" is going to scale with the number of items you're holding in memory at the same time, as is the run-time. When I see 24 *million* iterations, 30 minutes doesn't sound unreasonable, but with the scant amount of code provided your biggest performance hit is using `Application.WorksheetFunction`. I'd replace that with your own VBA implementation.

Comment: 1) this seems to be causing by some definitions, I will take this off as it is not relevant. FYI, we want to set a tenor to MAX 10Years, which is not properly reflected. 2) When you say replace that with my own VBA implementation, What do you mean? Simillar to `INT(InputMatrix(n,3)`, except round up- is there such a function?

Comment: There is if you write one.  ;-)